# Best way to handle script initialization for desktop and mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a platform that can detect if the device is on mobile, and I am using a js script which I want to have different settings when viewed on mobile. I am just asking if there's any way that I can do this maybe simpler? This is my sample code:

```
function loadKwicks(){
  function desk(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        minSize: 20,
        behavior: 'menu',
        duration: 500,
        autoResize:true
      });
    },500)
  }
  function mob(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        minSize: 80,
        behavior: 'menu',
        duration: 500,
        autoResize:true,
        isVertical:true
      });
    },500)
  }

  if (data.device === "mobile") {
    mob();
  } else {
    desk();  
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same.... But written differently.

```
function loadKwicks(){
  var mobSettings = {
    minSize: 80,
    behavior: 'menu',
    duration: 500,
    autoResize:true,
    isVertical:true
  };

  var deskSettings = {
    minSize: 20,
    behavior: 'menu',
    duration: 500,
    autoResize:true
  };

  var settings = (data.device === "mobile") ? mobSettings : deskSettings;

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.kwicks').kwicks(settings);
  },500);
}
```

And it can be shortened more!

```
function loadKwicks(){
  var settings = [
    {
      minSize: 20,      // Desktop settings
      behavior: 'menu',
      duration: 500,
      autoResize:true
    },
    {
      minSize: 80,      // Mobile settings
      behavior: 'menu',
      duration: 500,
      autoResize:true,
      isVertical:true
    }
  ];

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.kwicks').kwicks(settings[(data.device === "mobile")?1:0]);  // True will evaluate as 1
  },500);
}
```

Comment: Oh that's cleaner and simpler! Why didn't I thought about that it is an object thanks for the tip! :D